# SQL Server SQL Statement - Updating record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data as below:

[image]

I need to update `Matching_id` and `Matching_Type` by using `column id, region, company, dept, subdept and amountsepend`. The logic is:

`Sum AmountSepend by Region, Company, Dept and SubDept`. If the sum amount is 0 then Matching_Type is 'Match' and Matching_id is the combination of the id for the matched record else 'Not Match' and Matching_id is the id. **SUM means the total sum of all records for same criteria regardless the AmountSepend is positive or negative.

Another important criteria is if the transaction is single record, meaning the total count by grouping by Region, Company, Dept and SubDept is 1 then Matching type is Not Match and Matching_UID is id regardless the AmountSepend is 0 or positive/negative value. Example id 8.

Below is the output:

[image]

Here the table and data script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackoverflowQuest](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Region] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Company] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Dept] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SubDept] [varchar](50) NULL,
[AmountSepend] [float] NULL,
[Matching_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Matching_Type] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How could I achieved such result ? Any help/hint would be appreciate

Comment: are you still looking for a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(Id INT,Region VARCHAR(100),Company INT,Dept INT,SubDept       
INT,AmtSpend INT,MatchingId VARCHAR(100),MatchingType VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Table(Id ,Region ,Company , Dept  ,SubDept ,AmtSpend )
SELECT 1,'NAM',12378,1,NULL,900 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'NAM',12378,1,NULL,-900 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'NAM',12370,1,23,1000 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'ASA',1234,9,12,5000 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'NAM',12370,1,23,-1000 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'ASA',1234,9,12,800 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'ASA',1234,9,12,-600 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'ASA',12311,6,NULL,200

UPDATE #Table SET MatchingId = MatchIds,MatchingType = 'Match'
FROM 
(
  SELECT T2.Company,STUFF( ( SELECT ',' + CAST(T3.Id AS VARCHAR) FROM #Table    
  T3 WHERE T2.Company = T3.Company FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') MatchIds
  FROM #Table T2
  JOIN 
    (
    SELECT T1.Company Company,SUM(T1.AmtSpend) Total
    FROM #Table T1
    GROUP BY T1.Company
    HAVING SUM(T1.AmtSpend) = 0
  )A ON A.Company = T2.Company
    GROUP BY T2.Company
 ) A 
WHERE A.Company = #Table.Company


UPDATE #Table SET MatchingId = CAST(Id AS VARCHAR),MatchingType = 'Not  
Match' WHERE ISNULL(MatchingId,'') = ''

SELECT * FROM #Table
```

Comment: are you sure your code will work correctly when the negative sum for same department is split into 2 or more records, e.g. not 900 vs -900 but 900 vs (-600 and -300)? You add only 2 values into MatchIds column.

Comment: See above users required output.They no need sum of negative values.They check only positive and equal negative value.

Comment: "Sum AmountSepend by Region, Company, Dept and SubDept" - to my opinion Sum means the total sum of all records for same criteria and not the sum of only 2. Having only 1 positive and 1 negative records is just a simplified case of a general task. However, let the OP clarify.

Comment: SUM means the total sum of all records for same criteria regardless the AmountSepend is positive or negative.

Comment: I updated my post check now.Thanks for your suggesstion guys

Comment: This code doesn't work if I changed AmtSpend to 0 for row id 8. The correct value should be Not Match because the criteria is if the transaction is single record, meaning the total count by grouping by Region, Company, Dept and SubDept is 1 then Matching type is Not Match and Matching_UID is id regardless the AmountSepend is 0 or positive/negative value.

Comment: Grouping should by Region, Company, Dept and SubDept.

Comment: I noted that you changed company, dept and subdept to int data type. These must be varchar.